# How do I implement Single Sign on. Applications are written in Blazor App and React JS

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly

I need to implement the Single Sign on with Azure AD B2C. One of our application is developed in Blazor and other is developed in React JS.

Once user logged in Blazor app and then come to React JS app, he should be directly logged in without entering the credentials.

Thanks

Multiple Blazor app are able to work with SSO, but not the React JS app.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is only specific to Azure AD/ Microsoft SSO then you can use Microsoft Authentication Library for React (msal-react).The library will be useful for React or JS based client application to authenticate using Azure AD.
Refer this for more information-
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-react

Comment: This work if you are only using React based client application. I have 2 apps one with Blazor and other with ReactJS. Its not working when user login in blazor app and then open the react app. He still have to login.